# Dropbox filesGetTemporaryLink

Tags: dropbox, dropbox-api

I'm using `filesGetTemporaryLink` from the Dropbox API to get get a link to download a file. I save the link returned from this method to my db. It works for the most part but seemingly randomly I get a 410 error.

I'm wondering if these links are no longer accessible after a certain amount of time (I guess that could be expected from the name but I couldn't find another method to get a dl link). Should I be using something other than `filesGetTemporaryLink` to get a link I can save to my db?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links returned by [`filesGetTemporaryLink`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesGetTemporaryLink__anchor) do expire after four hours, at which point you will get that 410 error when trying to access them.

If you need a link that doesn't expire by default, you can use [`sharingCreateSharedLinkWithSettings`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#sharingCreateSharedLinkWithSettings__anchor) instead, and modify the resulting link as documented [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/desktop-web/force-download). Note that those links do get listed in [the user's links list](https://www.dropbox.com/share/links) though.

If you can avoid the need to have a link, you can instead download the file data using [`filesDownload`](https://dropbox.github.io/dropbox-sdk-js/Dropbox.html#filesDownload), which would be preferable.

Comment: I'm using `filesDownload` and I'm getting back a file in a form of a buffer array. My concern is that in case a file is too big, it can have a negative impact on a server load and performance. Could you please have a look on my question on this subject: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62740008